# asio udp multicast sending and receiving on the same host using loopback on the same interface

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, multicast

I'm currently trying to implement the SOME/IP protocol which uses multicast for the service discovery. The Language is c++ and the asio library (without boost) is used in my case.

Currently the code works, but only on 2 diffrent machines. When i try multicast between the 2 apps on the same host i also receive the messages that i just send out. I understand that this is the purpose of the loopback interface, which is enabled when running on the same host but i'm wondering how you could filter out the own messages that were just send and not receive them again? As implementing the standard with that behaviour on one machine is nearly impossible.
When i bind the one programm to my ethernet interface and the other to my wifi interface a normal connection is possible without receiving the your own messaged again after sending.

Is it normal when you implement a network protocol to have 2 machines for testing or am i missing a simple settings which enables me to send / receive from 2 programms to the same multicast , on the same interface, without receiving its own send messages?

Essentially i want to send / receive with 2 programms on the same interface to the same multicast address without also receiving my own messages in each programm after sending them.

Thanks in advance for the help. If you have further question or if my explanation is not good to understand just ask please

I already tried using diffrent ports on the same machine, which resulted in no receiving of any data.

Comment: _"...Is it normal when you implement a network protocol to have 2..."_ Normally; however the following will also work: 1 computer with 2 or more network cards; or 1 computer with VMs to host additional clients.  Also a protocol analyser like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is invaluable.

Comment: I already am using wireshark to make sure packets are transfered / received. Is there maybe a possibility to use virtual network interfaces for this kind of work? So i would bind the 1 client to my eth0 and the other to a virtual network interface?